# Cannot use variables in fetch API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm new to react development.
I tried to create a simple project which searches for the weather of a city by using an API.
Using fetch I tried to call the API:

```
getWeather = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=${API_KEY}';
    const api_call = await fetch(url);
    const data = await api_call.json() ;
    console.log(data);
}
```

But when I submit, the console log says wrong API KEY.
Instead if I give the API key directly into the URL it works, can somebody help me?

Comment: Use template string. You set just a string ${API_KEY} it needs to be a variable.
const url = \`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=${API_KEY}\`;

Comment: Where is `API_KEY` being set?

Comment: This is what Alexandr means: use like this     const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=${API_KEY}`;

Comment: You can use backticks instead of a single quote. ``https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=${API_KEY}``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that you're using the incorrect type of quotes. you're using `'` (single-quote or apostrophe) and you need to be using backticks, it's the key to the left of the `1` key on most keyboards if you want to use string interpolation (that's what the `${}` is called)

Comment: Glad to be of service! If the solution worked for you please mark it as accepted so that when others find this question they can easily see the solution